# React repeated onInput handlers in components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that looks like the one given below.

The form inputs are handled using the `onInputChange` function and form submit is handled by `onFormSubmit`

```
function RegisterForm() {
  // formData stores all the register form inputs.
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(registerDefault);
  const [errors, posting, postData] = useDataPoster();

  function onInputChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    let update = { [event.target.name]: event.target.value };

    setFormData(oldForm => Object.assign(oldForm, update));
  }

  function onFormSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const onSuccess: AxiosResponseHandler = response => {
      setFormData(Object.assign(formData, response.data));
    };

    postData("/api/register", formData, onSuccess);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
      <FormTextInput
        name="full_name"
        label="Name"
        errors={errors.full_name}
        onChange={onInputChange}
      />
      <FormTextInput
        name="email"
        label="Email address"
        type="email"
        errors={errors.email}
        onChange={onInputChange}
      />
      <button type="submit" className="theme-btn submit" disabled={posting}>
        {posting && <span className="fas fa-spin fa-circle-notch"></span>}
        Create
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

My app has more than 50 similar forms and I wonder if I have to copy paste these two functions on all the other forms. `onInputChange` won't be changing a bit and the url is the only variable in `onFormSubmit`.

I am thinking of a class based approach with `setFormData` and `postData` as properties and the functions in question as class methods. But in that case, I have to `bind` the handlers with the class instance, so that handlers have a valid `this` instance.

Is there any other way to do this? How would you avoid the repetition of these two code blocks in all the form components?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a custom hook, something like this:

```js
const [formState, setFormState] = useFormStateHandler({name: ''})

<input value={formState.name} onChange={event => setFormState(event, 'name')} />
```

where the definition looks like this:

```js
export default function useFormStateHandler(initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

  const updater = (event, name) => {
    setState({...state, [name]: event.target.value})
  }

  return [state, updater]
}
```

Comment: This looks good. If I return the `setState` also, then I will be able to directly change the state in the component (if required). I am waiting for all possible options. Do you have any other solutions? What do you think about the class based approach I've mentioned. Is there any cons to that?

Comment: both class based HOC or a custom hook like this does the job the same, i just prefer writing in hooks since it came out, and yeah, of ever you need some custom state updates the `setState` could just be passed too.

Comment: This answer was selected purely on the basis of personal preference. Creating a custom hook looked cleaner especially when my app is already using hooks wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Create an HOC to inject input handlers to the form components with added params for `url`.

```
function RegisterForm(props) {
  // specific function
  const specific = () => {
    const formData = props.formData; // use passed state values
    // use form data
  }
}

function withInputHandlers(Component, params) {
  return function(props) {
      // states
      function onInputChange(...) {...}
      function onFormSubmit(...) {
        // use params.url when submitting
        postData(params.url, formData, onSuccess);
      }
      // inject input handlers to component and state values
      return (
        <Component {...props} formData={formData} onChange={onInputChange} onSubmit={onFormSubmit} />
      );
  }
}

// Usage
const EnhancedRegisterForm = withInputHandlers(
  RegisterForm,
  { url: 'register_url' } // params
);

const EnhancedSurveyForm = withInputHandlers(
  Survey,
  { url: 'survey_url' } // params
)
```

Comment: I like this approach. But this look closed for update. What if there are other functions specific to a component and needs access to the states?

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan, you can also inject the states to the component. For other functions specific to the component will just be inside the component itself. I've updated the code showing such.

Answer (score 0):

This change may help you

```
function RegisterForm() {
  // formData stores all the register form inputs.
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(registerDefault);
  const [errors, posting, postData] = useDataPoster();

  const onInputChange = name => event => {
    let update = { [name]: event.target.value };

    setFormData(oldForm => Object.assign(oldForm, update));
  }

  const onFormSubmit = url => event =>{
    event.preventDefault();

    const onSuccess: AxiosResponseHandler = response => {
      setFormData(Object.assign(formData, response.data));
    };

    postData(url, formData, onSuccess);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit("/api/register")}>
      <FormTextInput
        name="full_name"
        label="Name"
        errors={errors.full_name}
        onChange={onInputChange("full_name")}
      />
      <FormTextInput
        name="email"
        label="Email address"
        type="email"
        errors={errors.email}
        onChange={onInputChange("email")}
      />
      <button type="submit" className="theme-btn submit" disabled={posting}>
        {posting && <span className="fas fa-spin fa-circle-notch"></span>}
        Create
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I was trying to share `onInputChange` and `onFormSubmit` code with multiple components.